# Sprite drag drop andengine

Tags: android, andengine

How to drag an andEngine sprite anywhere on the phone screen?

I have written this code in `onAreaTouched` function of `IOnAreaTouchListener` interface which is implemented in my activity, but its not working:

```
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
      ITouchArea pTouchArea, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
      float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.v(TAG,"Sprite Touched ##########");


    secondSprite = new 
    Sprite( CAMERA_WIDTH/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2, 
            playerTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                                     final float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                                     final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            secondSprite.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
            System.out.println(String.format("spriteB %fx%f", pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), 
                pSceneTouchEvent.getY()));
            return true;
        }
    };
    scene.registerTouchArea(secondSprite);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the behaviour you're currently getting?

Comment: You don't add secondSprite to your scene by the way.